# How do I code makecert "-sky exchange" and "-sky signature" in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, encryption-asymmetric, makecert

I need to programatically create the equivalant keys in a .NET application...

`makecert -r -pe -a sha1 -n "CN=MyName" -ss my -sr CurrentUser -sky exchange`

`makecert -r -pe -a sha1 -n "CN=MyName" -ss my -sr CurrentUser -sky signature`

The output will ultimately be used like this:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider privateKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();         
privateKey.FromXmlString("<RSAKeyValue>
<Modulus>wL8s+C8SnnlaaqR+VsyijmxOJOARNa4o7ZNsqfy3+9J9Ol2JNSjjMfQWoUnFtClzJBlZhU5KtuazQe8ZKXTX9YvKoJdRhlsonZkC04qiTMdO/FZIH00GrCRxeQ7XDnQnvPB9Bdsvs//7zrY3f7eLIkpIyK9cQHU+5jjJd5IT0eE=</Modulus>
<Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
<P>83xxN7jvpg5z16pxz2tIQIdqd/EfmikR9Q2TjG2tosWkUSvtyx0xHZ9EqdTUbSGZZ+jgrabzkafYc7Mplylwew==</P>
<Q>yqcnYSZEXHwJvRWi2V09PNEENTozQZywcFptUUGar9TciaQvoNv3lpnfzUKNBRdhzq4lImxkamajZlTWE5buUw==</Q>
<DP>37HqilkbwyHwB6mOGhPkM3S1ujAK6qTk3JB2iEOTjMGrru9+7maJYz+Z47Wm3ARMXgyzrpZ9m8nqsJFfmoL11Q==</DP>
<DQ>v285tv8kMs2FkZYfuP/oOkwkkneBNejjj68Md2bmzlThZDCyQV2pvB1tmgPVHUsiPNCrCaKlFRISJzfa5rR8Ow==</DQ>
<InverseQ>fgJE2TRe/SS+YqW0/I+FtHrdfbbao0/R3pHD4r4oceZQUemlBgZ7DxOAetebHKthlOdjGkmfWYB8EU4XoWggqw==</InverseQ>
<D>FMLCwjy3wbAKiCANp6XFAJgz1o7365NFv0k41BpvasViTa4TgFFWH2ROJ7M9g0lPqJy+YrhrHcY9mqV5TVjTheQp0JeckrgO2B39XngPMAMMdne3rWGpf0Pfbj3FLfchMk6XYDXSZzCS2CmSeRA4aBMb+4R3YurixyJLrnGRMH0=</D>
</RSAKeyValue>");
```

Comment: `makecert` creates a keypair and an X509 certificate. It looks like you are only using the keypair. Do you need the certificate?

Comment: @GregS I thought an X509 was the public cert, and the pks file is the pair (protected by a password).   The word keypair is throwing me off...

Answer (score 0):

I realize you probably have found a solution by now, but here is what the code would look like:  (based on http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2005/02/02/365323.aspx)

`Process.Start("makecert.exe", "-pe -n \"CN=MyCert Root Authority\" -ss my -sr LocalMachine -a sha1 -sky signature -r \"MyCert Root Authority.cer\"");`

`Process.Start("makecert.exe", "-pe -n \"CN=MyCert\" -ss my -sr LocalMachine -a sha1 -sky exchange -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -in \"MyCert Root Authority\" -is MY -ir LocalMachine -sp \"Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider\" -sy 12 \"MyCert.cer\"");`